# Website's performance is so bad at peak time

Tags: security, performance-testing

I need a tool or solution to use a very crowded website on specified time as using it as a normal user will not allow me to buy the something i want to buy on certain time . All help is appreciated

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate on the question.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to ask?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: simply my problem is : applying for a university is not easy beacuse more than thousands of students trying to fill the application on the website , so the website at that moment will be very slow and not responsive at all because of the huge number of users then , and if i waited for the website to response i won't find a place for me in the university ,,,  is there is any solution or a way to avoid website's bad performance then??